# Launch a process from Objective-C on the desktop

Tags: java, objective-c, macos, desktop-application

We have a java app which we call with a parameter (a selected folder), which works fine in C#.

However, I'm at a loose end to work out how to do this in Objective-C; I've found the LaunchApplication command, but it's a bit vague.

Can someone please help me out?

---

I've tried the following:

```
[[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] openFile:@"/Users/tharvey/Desktop/Test.jar" withApplication:@"/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/1.6.0/Home/bin/java"];
```

Which throws an error in the console about being unable to start the java app and also:

```
 NSTask *javaApp = [[NSTask alloc] init];
 [javaApp setLaunchPath:@"/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/1.6.0/Home/bin/java"];

 NSArray *javaAppArguments = [[NSArray alloc] init];
 javaAppArguments = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@" -jar ", @"/Users/tharvey/Desktop/Test.jar", nil];
 [javaApp setArguments:javaAppArguments];

 [javaApp launch];
```

However the above code doesn't work; and doesn't throw an error.

Unless launching the jar will work on it's own?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As it's a Java app, not a document as such, you should be fine to do:

```
NSString *jarPath = @"/Users/tharvey/Desktop/Test.jar"
[[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] openFile:jarPath];
```

(Assuming the app can normally be launched by double-clicking in the Finder)

Comment: This is missing a semicolon, btw

Answer (score 1):

Try using NSWorkspace:

[[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] openFile:@"~/Documents" withApplication:@"/Applications/MyApp.app"];